# Extending S/4HANA OData service to SCP

Tags: sapui5, hana, sap-cloud-platform

I want to extend a custom OData service created in a S/4HANA system. I added a Cloud Connector to my machine, but I don't know how to go from there. The idea is that I want people to access the service from SCP and that I don't need multiple accounts accessing the service on the S/4 system, but just the one coming from SCP. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the CC installed and configured in your cloud platform account? You'll find you have an entry for your S/4 system in the destinations section of the cockpit. Use that destination in your apps. Check the destinations authentication settings to see how it connects. You can chose username/pw there.

Comment: The idea is that I'm not going to use it in SCP apps. I want to be able to call the service from a Microsoft Excel plugin for OData. Basically just extend the service from S/4HANA to SCP to Excel.

Comment: Yeah, app doesn't have to be SCP so I see no problem with that. Be aware of the implications of what SAP calls "indirect licensing" though.

Comment: I get how to use the destination in an actual application. But I can't seem to call it in the browser. Any tips or documentation I can look at to help me solve it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I feel silly doing this but it seems to work. My test is actually inconclusive because I don't have a cloud connector handy, but it works proxy-ing google.

*I'm still thinking about how to make it publicly accessible*. There might be people with better answers than this.

1. create the cloud connector destination.
2. make a new folder in webide
3. create file `neo-app.json`.

content:

```
{
    "routes": [{
        "path": "/google",
        "target": {
            "type": "destination",
            "name": "google"
        },
        "description": "google"
    }],
    "sendWelcomeFileRedirect": false
}
```

`path` is the proxy in your app, so `myapp.scp-account/google` here. the target name is your destination. I called it just google, you'll put your cloud connector destination.

4. Deploy.

My test app with destination `google` going to `https://www.google.com` came out looking like this. Paths are relative so it doesn't work but google seems proxied.

You'll still have to authenticate etc.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @MatthijsMennens Let me know how it turns out, kind of curious. I am serious about those [indirect licencing](http://www.bluet.com.au/2018/03/18/group-therapy-for-sap-customers-seeking-licensing-clarity/) fees though.

Comment: Yeah I know, but its not something we're going to use in a production environment